# Julia: Syntax for indexing into an n-dimensional array without fixing n

Tags: multidimensional-array, interpolation, julia

I'm trying to use Julia's **Interpolations** package to interpolate a function sampled on an n-dimensional grid. The Interpolations package uses a syntax similar to array indexing for specifying the point at which to interpolate the data (in fact it appears that the Interpolations package imports the getindex function used for array indexing from Base). For example for n=2 the following code:

```
using Interpolations 

A_grid = [1 2; 3 4]
A = interpolate((0:1, 0:1), A_grid, Gridded(Linear()))
a = A[0.5, 0.5]
println(a)
```

prints the result of a linear interpolation at the midpoint (0.5, 0.5).

Now, if I have an n-dimensional vector (e.g. `index_vector = [0.5, 0.5]` in n=2 dimensions), I see that I can get the same result by writing

```
a = A[index_vector[1], index_vector[2]]
```

but I am unable to do this in general. That is, I would like to find/write a function that takes an n-dimensional array `A` and a vector `index_vector` of length n and returns

```
A[index_vector[1], ... , index_vector[n]]
```

where n is not known beforehand. Is there a way to do this when the entries of `index_vector` are not necessarily integers?

Comment: can't you use the splat (`...`) operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the splat (`...`) for that. `...` "distributes" the elements of a collection to argument slots:

```
using Interpolations 

A_grid = [1 2; 3 4]
A = interpolate((0:1, 0:1), A_grid, Gridded(Linear()))
index_vector = [0.5, 0.5]
a = A[index_vector...]
println(a)
```

gives the same result of your example.